# Setting IEDriverServer location with protractor

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, gruntjs, protractor

Where do I define the IEDriverServer path? Is it in the protractor config file? If so, how do I do it correctly?
I've been looking for ages but most solutions seem to give answers for java, i'm using protractor with grunt and node, whenever I run the grunt task I have made for IE or change the capabilities browser name to IE I get the following error in the console/webstorm console:

> The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property;

a search for that usually takes me to an article that guides me to

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

but to be honest that's not much help past downloading the driver, as it doesn't say where, or how, I set that system property.

Hope I'm being clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path in question is the environment variable PATH. You can test this by placing the driver executable in somewhere like `C:\Windows\System32\` that ought to be in the PATH already, and running the tests.

To add a directory to the PATH, navigate to Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables and locate Path in the bottom window. Select it and click Edit. Enter the directory here, separating it from the previous directory with a semi-colon. For example, you might add the following to the end of the existing path:

`;C:\Drivers\`

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me, added it to both the 'PATH' in the 'user variables for username' and the 'Path' 'System variables'

this is where my drivers are kept and is what i added to both of the above, chromedriver is also in there and that works fine and always has

C:\Source\WebApp\Beech\node_modules\protractor\selenium

Comment: OK so adding the driver to system 32 folder works (although its unbelievably slow but that's a problem for another day) any idea why the path i want to use isn't working?

Comment: Ensure that you've separated it from the previous directory with a semi-colon, and that you've ended it with a forward-slash.

Comment: ok its working now. so basically for anyone who wants to know in the 'Path' under 'System variables' i had ;C:\Source\;C:\Source\WebApp\Beech\node_modules\protractor\selenium\
i dont know why but this did not work, but i took out the ;C:\Source\ and now its working as expected.

Comment: did you ever get this to speed up?  It's unusably slow for me

Comment: Unfortunately not. In my case I'm fortunate enough to only need to support Firefox, so I didn't spend too long trying to make IE enter data at anything more than a character every other second..!

Comment: @Erik Only just saw this comment, so you may have fixed it, regardless of your system use the 32bit IEDriver that one works at a normal speed.